# Spring XML Namespaces

Tags: xml, spring, config

I'm currently working my way through 'Spring in Action'. Being stuck starting with the aspects, I'd like to know if anybody can see my mistake.
In my AppConfig.xml, I start the bean-declaratiotn with:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
```

Running the app, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [config/AppConfig.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
```

The definition might be wrong?

Any help appreciated!

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: The isn't a config error, it's a missing library error. Are you deploying the aop dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have spring-aop.jar, aopalliance.jar or aspectjtools-1.6.0.jar included in your project.  The error is indicating that the Advice class is not found on your class path. It can be found in one of the two jars I mentioned depending on the version of Spring you are using.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82282-ava-lang-ClassNotFoundException-org-aopalliance-aop-Advice

Comment: actually, it was the aspectjtools-1.6.0.jar that was missing, the spring-distribution seems to be complete. nothing to exploring the realm of new languages 8)

Comment: @Marcus Toepper thanks for updating, I edited my answer to include your find.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced same issue while starting a application development Spring 3.0 release.

AOP is removed from 3.0 release.

So,you need to explicitly download and have this particular jar { **aopalliance-1.0.jar** } in your classpath .

This will solve the problem.